# Marginalisation of a joint probability distribution in bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, notation, quantum-states, identical-particles

Given a wave function $\Psi(\vec r_1, \vec r_2)$, where $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ are the positions of particle 1 and 2, respectively, the probability of finding particle 1 at position $\vec r$ (irrespective of particle 2) is the marginalised probability distribution
$$P_1(\vec r) = \int |\Psi(\vec r,\vec r_2)|^2 d^3\vec r_2. \tag 1$$

Similarly, the probability of finding particle 2 at position $\vec r$ is the marginalised distribution
$$P_1(\vec r) = \int |\Psi(\vec r_1,\vec r)|^2 d^3\vec r_1. \tag 2$$

**Question:** How can I do this marginalisation in bra-ket notation? Given a ket $|\Psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$, where $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ are the Hilbert spaces of particle 1 and 2, respectively, how do I define the probability of finding particle 1 at position $\vec r$ (irrespective of particle 2)?

**Attempt**: My guess to translate $(1)$ into bra-ket notation would be something like
$$P_1(\vec r) = |\langle \vec r_1 | \Psi \rangle |^2,$$

where $\langle \vec r_1|$ only acts on the part of $|\Psi\rangle$ which is in $\mathcal{H}_1$. However, this is a notational mess because $\langle \vec r_1|$ (which is actually $\langle \vec r|$, an eigenstate of the position operator) does not have the same symbol as the argument of the function $P_1$.

Furthermore, how do I denote that nothing happens to the part of $|\Psi\rangle$ which is in $\mathcal{H}_2$? Shouldn't one write something like
$$P_1(\vec r)=|\left(\langle \vec r_1 | \otimes I \right) |\Psi \rangle|^2,$$

where $I$ is the identity operator on $\mathcal{H}_2$. But this is wrong because $\langle \vec r_1 | \otimes I $ is meaningless, as it is the tensor product of a vector and an operator.

Comment: Here are a few hints/ comments: 1.Read about the partial trace. 2. Your equations cannot be correct because the LHS is independent of $r_1$, whereas the RHS is not. 3. Regarding the meaning of the tensor product of the operator with the bra / ket, see for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76770/question-about-the-dirac-notation-for-partial-trace). You will see exactly this type of object a lot in the field of quantum information theory, when defining the partial trace. 4. You're almost there :) (again, compare to the notion of partial trace, e.g. in the linked post).

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Thanks! I'll have a look at the partial trace. Regarding point 2.: To fix this problem, I was thinking of writing $P_1(\vec r) = |\langle \vec r | \Psi \rangle |^2$. But this has the problem that it isn't clear that $\langle r|$ only acts on the $\mathcal{H}_1$ part of $|\Psi\rangle$.

Comment: Btw, I assumed that you meant two distinguishable particles, or, more generally, a Hilbert space structure like $H = H_1 \otimes H_2$.

Comment: Actually, I initially had two indistinguishable particles in my mind... (e.g. two electrons in the state $\Psi(\vec r_1, \vec r_2) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[ \Psi_A(\vec r_1)\Psi_B(\vec r_2) ± \Psi_B(\vec r_1) \Psi_A(\vec r_2)]$, where $\Psi_A$ and $\Psi_B$ are single-particle wave functions.)

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Is the answer perhaps $P_1(\vec r)=|\left(\langle \vec r | \otimes I \right) |\Psi \rangle|^2$, where $\langle \vec r | \otimes I$ is actually a well-defined object because $\langle \vec r|$ and $I$ are operators.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: No, you have to trace out (integrate) the other degree of freedom. In the case of identical particles, I think it doesn't make much sense to speak of $P_i$ (i.e. about particle 1 and particle 2$... As far as I know, one often considers the p-particle reduced density matrices, which follow a similar notion.

Comment: E.g. in this case, the probability distribution to find *one* particle at $x$ is given by $n(x) = 2\, \displaystyle \int \mathrm d y\, |\psi(x,y)|^2$, which is the diagonal element of the 1-body reduced density matrix, $\gamma(x,x^\prime)$. Due to the lack of a concrete reference (but I'm sure you'll find something), see for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/338118/one-body-reduced-density-matrix). Edit: For a concrete definition, cf. *Lieb, Seiringer. The stability of Matter in Quantum Mechanics, ch. 3.1.5.* (but no bra-ket notation is used, tho).

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Thank you, but would it be possible to write an answer? :)